# Oracle SQL Stored Procedure Returning Set

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I thinks it's simple.

I have a table `People` with columns `Name`, `Surname` and `Age`.

I want a stored procedure `GetPersonsBySurname` with

- input  -> a set of surnames
- output -> name, surname and age of the people in that set of surnames.

Thank you in advance.

Now I have this... I can write a stored procedure with only one surname...
I want a set of surnames instead...

Here are my code

Table

```
CREATE TABLE "PEOPLE" 
(
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "SURNAME" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "AGE" NUMBER(*,0)
)
```

Header

```
create or replace PACKAGE "MYPACK" IS 

TYPE r_output IS RECORD 
(     

    name varchar2(255), 
    surname  varchar2(255), 
    age varchar2(255)

);

TYPE CURS_R_OUTPUT IS REF CURSOR
  RETURN r_output;

PROCEDURE GetPersonsBySurname ( mysurname in varchar2,
                                    OUT_P_CUR                       OUT CURS_R_OUTPUT,
                                    OUT_ESITO                       OUT VARCHAR2,
                                    OUT_MESSAGGIO                   OUT VARCHAR2
);

END MYPACK;
```

Body

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY "MYPACK" 
IS
PROCEDURE GetPersonsBySurname  ( mysurname in varchar2,
                                    OUT_P_CUR                       OUT CURS_R_OUTPUT,
                                    OUT_ESITO                       OUT VARCHAR2,
                                    OUT_MESSAGGIO                   OUT VARCHAR2
                                    )
AS     
BEGIN

  OPEN OUT_P_CUR FOR
      select p.name, p.surname, p.age
      from people p
      where p.surname = mysurname ;


 EXCEPTION
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND 
 THEN
     OUT_ESITO := 'OK';
     OUT_MESSAGGIO := 'No data found';

 WHEN OTHERS
 THEN
     OUT_ESITO := 'KO';
     OUT_MESSAGGIO := 'ERROR';

 END GetPersonsBySurname;

 END MYPACK;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please ask specific questions, show the code that you have already written and explain where exactly you are stuck at. This is not a site that turns software requirements and specification from plain English into runnable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare yourself a schema-level collection type:

```
create or replace type surnames_coll
as
table of varchar2(255 byte)
;
```

Then implement this stored procedure inside your package:

```
procedure GetPersonsByMultipleSurnames
    ( mysurnames                    in surnames_coll
    , out_p_cur                     out curs_r_output
    , out_esito                     out varchar2
    , out_messaggio                 out varchar2 )
as
begin
    open out_p_cur for
      select p.name, p.surname, p.age
      from table(mysurnames) x
          join people p
              on p.surname = X.column_value
    ;
exception
    when others then
        out_esito := 'KO';
        out_messaggio := 'ERROR';
end GetPersonsByMultipleSurnames;
```

The, from the PL/SQL, instead of

```
mypack.GetPersonsBySurname(
    mysurname => 'Esposito',
    out_p_cur => my_p_cur,
    out_esito => my_esito,
    out_messaggio => my_out_messaggio
);
```

you are going to call

```
mypack.GetPersonsByMultipleSurnames(
    mysurnames => surnames_coll('Esposito','Grande','con Carne','...'),
    out_p_cur => my_p_cur,
    out_esito => my_esito,
    out_messaggio => my_out_messaggio
);
```

Of course, the output ref cursor suggests that you are not going to call this from PL/SQL but rather from Java or .NET or something like that. In that case the stored procedure could be different.

**A test:**

Suppose you have the following data inserted in your `people` table:

```
insert into people (name, surname, age) values ('Juan', 'Esposito', 1);
insert into people (name, surname, age) values ('Pablo', 'Esposito', 2);
insert into people (name, surname, age) values ('Maria', 'con Carne', 3);
insert into people (name, surname, age) values ('Chili', 'con Carne', 4);
insert into people (name, surname, age) values ('Ernesto', 'Grande', 5);
insert into people (name, surname, age) values ('Pedro', 'Grande', 6);
insert into people (name, surname, age) values ('Che', 'del Puerto', 5);
insert into people (name, surname, age) values ('Rita', 'del Puerto', 6);
```

Then a simple test run in SQL*Plus with surnames of `Esposito`, `con Carne` and `Grande` will yield

```
SQL> var l_people_cursor refcursor;
SQL> var l_esito varchar2(32);
SQL> var l_messagio varchar2(4000);
SQL> 
SQL> begin
  2          mypack.GetPersonsByMultipleSurnames(
  3          mysurnames => surnames_coll('Esposito','Grande','con Carne', '...'),
  4          out_p_cur => :l_people_cursor,
  5          out_esito => :l_esito,
  6          out_messaggio => :l_messagio
  7          );
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> 
SQL> print l_esito;

L_ESITO                                                                         
--------------------------------                                                


SQL> print l_messagio;

L_MESSAGIO                                                                      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


SQL> 
SQL> col name format a10
SQL> col surname format a20
SQL> 
SQL> print l_people_cursor;

NAME       SURNAME                     AGE                                      
---------- -------------------- ----------                                      
Pablo      Esposito                      2                                      
Juan       Esposito                      1                                      
Pedro      Grande                        6                                      
Ernesto    Grande                        5                                      
Chili      con Carne                     4                                      
Maria      con Carne                     3                                      

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**PS:** The `exception when no_data_found then` exception handler in your original function is completely useless. Opening a cursor will *never* raise this exception.

**PS#2:** Returning `'ERROR'` in your `out_messagio` is a very bad practice. Instead, make the line to `out_messagio := sqlerrm;`